# Can't access ActiveRecord relations with "includes" in Rails 5 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 with a MySQL database and this is how my models look like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_activities
end
# Table: "users"

class UserActivity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
# Table: "user_activities"
```

To make it clear what I'd like to achieve, I'm going to show you an actually working query at first:

```
SELECT * FROM user_activities LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_activities.user_id WHERE (users.gender = 'female') LIMIT 1;
```

Nothing too special, right? The problem is that I don't really get this working in my Rails project. I read a few articles already but somehow I got stuck...

```
ua = UserActivity.includes(:user).where(users: {gender: 'female'}).limit(1) # <-- The "join" part of it works
# ua = UserActivity.includes(:user).where("users.gender = 'f'").limit(1) # <-- MySQL throws an error
puts ua.inspect # <-- Shows me only the attributes of my UserActivity class

puts ua.user.inspect # <-- Can't access anything
```

So my question is why I can not use "ua.user"?

Answer (score 0):

> ## ua = UserActivity.includes(:user).where("users.gender = 'f'").limit(1) # <-- MySQL throws an error

Includes loads the association data in a separate query, you should use eager_load instead, or you can use

```
UserActivity.includes(:users).references(:users).where("users.gender = 'f'").limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ua = UserActivity.eager_load(:user).where({users: {gender: 'female'}}).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
@user_activities = UserActivity.joins(:user).where("users.gender = female"})
```

Here @user_activities Gives You Array

```
@user_activities.each do |user_activity|
  user_activity.foo # It Will Give Their Class Attributes Values
  user_activity.try(:user).try(:gender)  # It Will Give User Class Attributes Values
end
```